# Finding the solution set for binary matrix and vector multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am trying to make a tracing algorithm, and currently have got a bit stuck on finding the optimal hypothesis. I will describe my approach below.

> Let $X$ be a binary $n$-vector, a function $f:X \rightarrow R^+$, $A$ - a sparse binary $m \times n$-matrix $(m \leq n)$ and $b$ a vector with $m$ ones.

For more context: $A$ is a matrix, where each column describes a possible relation between objects and each row represents an object, $X$ contains hypotheses, if $X_i = 1$ then $A$s' $i$th column is considered to be true, $f$ calculatess the product of likelihoods for each hypothesis.

I have to solve for $arg \max_{X}f(X)$ such that $A\cdot X=b$, where $(\cdot )$ is thought of as a regular dot product.

The current definition of function $f$ is more programmatic than mathematical, but I`m going to give it anyway. Every column of $A$ describes a relationship between objects, and for every relationship we can calculate the likelihood of it being true. The likelihood of it not being true is assumed to be $1 -$ *likelihood of it being true*. Given $X$ we multiply all the resulting likelihoods together.

If $n$ is small enough the solution can be found by simply checking all the possible $2^n$ options of $X$. However, with larger $n$-s the previous method becomes computationally unfeasible, therefore I attempted to find the solution set to the indeterminate system.

I denote solution set as such: $X = B\cdot x^* + c$, where $x^* $ is a binary $k$-vector of independent variables from previous system, $B$ is a $n\times k$-matrix and $c$ is $n$-vector. $B_{ij}$ is $i$-th original variables' dependancy on $j$-th independent variable and $c_{i}$ is a bias. With this method I can reduce the problem to $2^k$ calculations yielded by all possible $x^*$s. However, there are problems with this method, for example, not every $x*$ will yield a binary vector, but more importantly not every solution set will yield even one valid solution.

My observation is, that if the solution set contains at least one valid solution, then it also contains the most optimal solution.

With this method I get a valid solution roughly 97.5% of the times.

My question is, is there a more reliable way of finding all the valid $X$s that meet the required conditions without having to check all $2^n$ options. And is even my approach correct, or the fact that I find both  valid and optimal solutions just dumb luck?

Comment: When you say you need $X$ to satisfy $AX = b$ (that is a matrix-vector product by the way, not a dot product), are we doing arithmetic over $\mathbb F_2$ (the finite field on $\{0, 1\}$) here? Or do you just want $AX \geq b$, i.e. each entry of $AX$ has to be at least 1? In that case, the problem would basically be the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete. This makes me think that without quantifiable knowledge of $A$ or $f$ it will be hard to make any algorithmic improvement.

Comment: @Watercrystal Arithmetic over $\mathbb{F}_2$ would yield wrong answers due addition behaving like a XOR gate. And I want $AX=b$ not $AX \geq b$. What kind of quantifiable knowledge about $A$ and $f$ would help me and how. They are fully defined beforehand. I'll add context on $f$ in the post.

Comment: @Watercrystal You were right, it is a set cover problem, more specifically, [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), for which there already exists algorithms. I'll see if I can implement any and post an answer myself.

Comment: Cool, do share your progress. Alternatively, you might want to look at SAT solvers. They are pretty fast due to some nice heuristics and could be a viable way to obtain exact solutions.

Comment: Hello @Watercrystal, I would like to notify you, that me and co-authors are planing to acknowledge your involvement in an upcoming article of ours. The problem you helped us solve has allowed to significantly accelerate our variant of Multiple Hypotheses Tracking. I am contacting you now as we are approaching a final version of the paper, and would like to have your consent on the acknowledgement.

Comment: Sure, that is nice of you. Is there any way to contact you privately for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Watercrystal I was able to classify the problem, and thus find a premade algorithm.

Firstly, we have to put the function $f$ aside for the main problem with this task was reducing the search space of the hypotheses.

The problem at hand is an **exact cover** problem. Which in its simplest form looks something like this:

> Say we have a set $U$ and collection $S$ consisting of subsets of $U$. The exact cover problem requires us to find all the possible combinations of subsets from S, such that each combination has exactly one of each item from $U$.

This case isn't much different, given $m\times n$ matrix - $A$ with the same definition as before, we know, that there are $m$ - objects, so $U=\{1,2,...,m\}$ and $S$ is a collection with $n$ subsets.

Example:

$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $

$U=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

$S = \{\{1\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{3\},\{1,2,3\},\{4\},\{1,2,4\},\{5\}\}$

The algorithm for finding all the combinations is called [Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X), and I'm not going to explain it, for I only need to use it.

A working python implementation can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/algorithm-x/).